# Asp.net project from IIS deployed site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a site deployed on iis however I can't seem to edit any of the backend code when I export it from IIS as a zip file. Is there any way to do this?

This is a asp.net mvc3 application as far as I can tell

Comment: is it a website or a web application? You can't edit the latter w/o the original source.

Comment: It's a asp.net mvc3 application as per what the source code looks like in the export

Comment: Pretty sure mvc only does web applications, you need the original source code which compiles into what's on the server.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that some of the application ddl is already compiled so I can't see the function methods when I export... I guess I'll have to ask the previous developers for their code

Comment: That is the best option, you can also decompile the dlls to get most of the code, google has several popular options there.

Answer (score 0):

all you code-behind becomes in a dll after compile application and you can find its in the BIN folder.